# Disproof: there exists an integer $k ≥ 4$ such that $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is prime.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Show that the following statement is false:
> There exists an integer $k ≥ 4$ such that $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is prime.

**Assume this is true:**

For all integers $k ≥ 4$, $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is not prime.

**Proof:**

Suppose $k ∈ Z$ such that $k ≥ 4$. By definition of prime, $n=rs$ for some integer $r$ and $s$, where $r = 1$ and $s = n$ or $r = n$ and $r = 1$. We want to show that $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is not prime. Then

$2k^2- 5k + 2 ≠rs$

$(2k - 1) (k-2) ≠ rs$

Notice that $2k-1>1$ and $k-2>1$, because $k ≥ 4$. Also, $2k-1$ and $k-2$ are less than $2k^2- 5k + 2$, which means it’s a product of two smaller integers. Therefore, $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is not prime, which is a contradiction to original theorem.∎

---

My first question is whether the definition of prime is needed when contradicting the statement. I thought that maybe the definition is not important, since it says:

> $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is not prime.

Another question is whether my concluding paragraph is too wordy.

This my first time doing a proof by contradiction.

Comment: they ask you to prove the claim is false. so you need to assume it is true, isn't it?

Comment: Actually no. It says prove that it's false. The opposite of an existential statement is a universal statement. The book where this statement comes says this.

Comment: prove the following claim is false: "claim: 1>2", what should you assume?

Comment: You do not need a contradiction proof. If you show (as you did , with a slight typo : $2k^2-1$ instead of $2k-1$) that $2k^2-5k+2$ is composite for every integer $k\ge 4$, you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Show that the following statement is false:
> > There exists an integer $k ≥ 4$ such that $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is prime.
>
> **Assume this is true:**
>
> For all integers $k ≥ 4$, $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is not prime.
>
> **Proof:**
>
> Suppose $k ∈ Z$ such that $k ≥ 4$. By definition of prime, $n=rs$ for
> some integer $r$ and $s$, where $r = 1$ and $s = n$ or $r = n$ and $r
>  = 1$. We want to show that $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is not prime. Then
>
> $2k^2- 5k + 2 ≠rs$
>
> $(2k - 1) (k-2) ≠ rs$
>
> Notice that $2k-1>1$ and $k-2>1$, because $k ≥ 4$. Also, $2k-1$ and
> $k-2$ are less than $2k^2- 5k + 2$, which means it’s a product of two
> smaller integers. Therefore, $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is not prime, which is a
> contradiction to original theorem.∎
>
> This my first time doing a proof by contradiction.

You repeatedly mix up "we want to show blah blah" and "we assume blah blah", making your proof illogical, and confusing to read. For example, despite your boldfaced opening heading, your proof's opening section is actually telegraphing what it wants to show rather than making an assumption (to assume something means to suppose, without any proof, that it is true; this supposition to be subsequently utilised in the proof).

It is clear that your proof is attempting to show that the given statement's negation is true, that is, that the statement itself is false; in other words, it is attempting to disprove the given statement. But a **proof of a negation** (what you are actually doing) is conceptually *different* from a **proof by contradiction** (what you think you are doing)!

- When proving a statement by contradiction, you start by assuming its negation, then derive some contradiction (***not necessarily*** involving the given statement or its negation), then conclude that the given statement must be true.
- When disproving a statement by contradiction, you start by assuming the given statement, then derive some contradiction (***not necessarily*** involving the given statement or its negation), then conclude that the given statement must be false.

For this exercise, proof by contradiction is unnecessary.

Comment: so, this is what I understood from your answer. Firstly, I should remove (We want to show that 2k2−5k+2 is not prime) because it contradicts with (Assume For all integers k≥4, 2k2−5k+2 is not prime); Right? secondly, proving a statement by contradiction means using the negation to reach a contradiction, proving the original statement is true. While disproving a statement by contradiction means using the same statement to reach a contradiction, disproving the given statement. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The meat of your proof has similar logic issues and needs to be revamped.  @Omar

Comment: Ok I will upvote more answers. 

Comment: I would appreciate if you explained the difference between proof by contradiction and proof by negation in more detail. Maybe give a source to learn more about proof in general, if you don't mind. Either way thanks for the help.

Comment: @Omar Your query needs to be more specific. Proof of a negation is self-evident. Proof by contradiction, I've discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4200978/21813), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4505319/21813), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4284272/21813), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4149381/21813), etc. $\quad$ P.S. The main reason to accept/upvote/downvote is to help sort the site and help it function better.

Comment: Ok thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

Prove the following claim is true: "$P$"

Prove by contradiction, assume "$\neg P$" is true.

Prove the following claim is false: "$Q$"

Prove by contradiction, assume "$\neg Q$" is false $\Leftrightarrow$ assume "$Q$" is true.

In your case:

> show that the following statement is false:
>
> > There exists an integer $k ≥ 4$ such that $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is prime.

$Q:$ "There exists an integer $k ≥ 4$ such that $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is prime."

So you should assume $Q$ is true, namely

Assume "There exists an integer $k ≥ 4$ such that $2k^2 − 5k + 2$ is prime." is true.

Comment: Ok, what you did is a direct proof for the statement: There exists an integer k≥4
 such that 2k2−5k+2 is prime. I want to proof by contradiction.

Comment: No, this is to prove by contradiction, can you read it carefully?

Comment: I am confused. My problem is that the textbook that I have says to negate a "∃x__ such that__" statement we should turn it into a "∀x, if --> then" statement